# OTBI Reporting in Oracle Cloud

Tags: oracle

I am doing reporting in OTBI (Oracle Cloud). Can any one help me to customize "General Ledger Trial Balance Report". I am getting error as

> ORA-20101: ORA-06512: at "FUSION.GL_GLGENLED_XMLP_PKG"

while editing the data model for the standard Report. Any one have any idea.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ORA-20101 isn't Oracle *built-in* error; codes from -20000 to -20999 are custom-reserved codes, so I suppose that it was used by developer who raised it in package/procedure you named. If you have access to it, search for "20101" and see why it happened.

ORA-06512, on the other hand, means that you hit an unhandled exception at line #4. That's good for troubleshooting (i.e. looking at that piece of code and find the culprit at line #4). But, if you don't/can't review that procedure, huh, you're in trouble. Basically, there are 3 ways out:

- fix the error yourself, if you can
- write an exception handler which will *handle* that situation (if you can)
- ask your DBA for help

I'm not sure whether you can do anything of above as it looks like Oracle-written procedure, so ...

Finally, your last resort is to contact Oracle Support and ask for assistance.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion Sir. And yes you are right, I guess I can't resolve the error by my own as it is oracle written package and unfortunately we don't have access to Oracle ERP Cloud Data Base. I guess in such case I need to raise SR with Oracle. But thanks again for your help. :)